# How can I get more than a variable from a $_POST?

Tags: php

In the purchase button of PayPal, there is an input hidden called custom. I can add on  him a variable to get it after.

The thing is, I want to get 2 variables.

Actually, I have in the value of the input this: `<php? echo $customform ?>`

And on **listener.php** (this receive the post data from paypal) i have got PHPmailer working with the custom variable.

like this: `$mail->Body = $_POST['custom'];`

So, Paypal only gives one custom field and i want to send something like this:

```
$customform $loginid
```

and then work with both variables. How can i do it guys? thank you so much.

Comment: Add another hidden input

Comment: Paypal only gives one custom field.

Comment: So add another? Or can you not change the code

Comment: I can't. One of the paypal variables it is custom and i only can work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize the variable's value into JSON and pass the data, once you get back the json from PayPal just unserialize it.

```
// get the user from database
$loggedInUser = 1;

$data = json_encode(array (
  'customForm' => $_POST['key'],
  'loginId' => $loggedInUser,
));

// {"customForm": "data1", "loginId": "1"}
```

and whey you get back the result just decode it back to an array.

```
$result = json_decode ($_POST['custom'], true);
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: How can insert php inside? i mean, where 'data1' i want to get a post. And where '1' i want to put a select from database. By the way, when json decode i dont understand how to get the variables separate. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your time, only the decode it's what i don't understand. What i supposed to use if i want to use loginId for example in the PHPmailer body?